# Specifying multiple Spring active profiles in k8s deployment yml

Tags: spring

I am having two active profiles in my module in Java.
I am trying to specify it in kubernetes like this:

```
env:
  - name: spring_profiles_active
    value: ["dev", "shop-module"]
```

Is the correct way to specify the two active configs?

Comment: If it is a normal Spring boot application deployment then this works: spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb

Comment: Wow, great answer mate!
Doesn't makes a sense to me how this works as one string, but it's fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple active profiles can be configured in the below way:

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb
```

(or)

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "dev,hsqldb"
```

Answer (score -1):

how do you pass it while on command line ?? it will be supported surely if can be done via command line or you can do outside of kubernetes

try this link,

[How can I specify the spring.profiles.active param with a value from an environment variable using fabric8 maven plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317820/how-can-i-specify-the-spring-profiles-active-param-with-a-value-from-an-environm)

Comment: you mean in intelliJ ???
it is 
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - "dev"
      - "shop-module"

Comment: but this is not related. I am asking how to specify more than one active profiles....

Comment: Dspring.profiles.active="default,dev", it shows that we should use string rather array, try without array